# Twitter Package for Python in Windows 7 is not working

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have installed Python 3.3 on Windows 7 machine with Twitter package...But it is throwing a syntax error:

```
C:\Python33\dist\python-oauth2-master>python setup.py build
  File "setup.py", line 18
    print "unable to find version in %s" % (VERSIONFILE,)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The above error is resolved now... Thanks for the help!!!

I tried with Python 2.7 but getting this error now...

```
>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
>>> trends = twitter_search.trends()

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
raise URLError(err)

URLError: <urlopen error 

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: This relies on python2.x apparently. Try installing python2.7

Comment: print is a function in python 3.x. Looks like the oauth2 does not support python3. Also, it looks like an outdated library (2 years old)

Comment: Check the package called [twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter) - should work for python 3.

Comment: I tried with Pythin 2.7 but getting this error now...

>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
>>> trends = twitter_search.trends()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>